# Can we have $x^n\equiv (x+1)^n \pmod m$ for large enough $n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$x^n\equiv (x+1)^n$ For what values of m and n can we find an x that solves this?

Comment: Is your question: "For every natural number $x$, can we have $x^n\equiv (x+1)^n$ ($\mod m$) for large enough $m$?" (where $m$ may depend on $x$)

Comment: No my question is if it is possible to find a number x such that $x^n=(x+1)^n$ for large values of $n$

Comment: Are you asking for the equation to hold for *all* sufficiently large values of $n$? For infinitely many? Or what? E.g. $3^n\cong 4^n\mod 7$ for all even $n$; more generally, $k^n\cong (k+1)^n\mod 2k+1$ for all even $n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not clear from your question what is fixed and what varies. To illustrate: suppose you want a solution with $n=10$ --- is that a large enough $n$? Very well, then --- pick your favorite $x$, say, $x=42$. Then calculate $43^{10}-42^{10}$ and call it $Q$. Then if $m$ is $Q$, or any factor of $Q$, you will have $(x+1)^n\equiv x^n\pmod m$.

If that's not what you want, please edit your question to clarify.

EDITing in things from the comments:

1. For fixed $n\gt3$ it is probably hard to find a useful characterization of those $m$ for which there is a solution.
2. For fixed $m$, let $n=\phi(m)$, then $x^n\equiv(x+1)^n\equiv1\pmod m$ provided $x$ and $x+1$ are relatively prime to $m$.
3. There are (lots of) solutions not of the form of item 2.

Comment: thats exactly what I want

Comment: For what values of m and n are there solutions?

Comment: $(x+1)^n-x^n$ is a polynomial of degree $n-1$, let's call it $p_n(x)$, and you are asking for which $m$ and $n$ is there a solution to the congruence $p_n(x)\equiv0\pmod m$. Even if you fix $n$ that's probably a hard question to answer for any $n\gt3$.

Comment: For some what there are what? Please write in complete, unambiguous sentences. That's what distinguishes Mathematics from everything else.

Comment: you're right. can we have for say: a fixed m greater than 7 that $x^n\equiv(x+1)^n\bmod m$ for some x and n?

Comment: For fixed $m$, let $n=\phi(m)$ (the Euler phi-function), then $x^n\equiv(x+1)^n\equiv1\pmod m$, provided $x$ and $x+1$ are both relatively prime to $m$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't chat.

Comment: This also holds for any multiple of $\phi (n)$ right? can we have solutions when that does not hold?

Comment: Yes, and yes. We've already seen examples of the latter, and a small amount of numerical experimentation on your part would undoubtedly uncover many more.

Comment: So in other words this isn't a very interesting question to pose. would you agree?

Comment: Interest is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: except the "interest is in the eye of the beholder" part

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of presenting a trivial example: we can even have it for small enough $m$. Just let $m=1$. Any integer (mod $1$) is equivalent to zero.

$x^n \equiv (x+1)^n$ (mod $1$).

EDIT: Your conjecture also holds if $n=0$. $x^0 = (x+1)^0$.

Comment: that's why I was asking for large enough n.

Comment: Except you weren't; your title and question have said $m$ for all (previous) revisions.

Comment: I don't have an immediate proof for this, but I don't think the conjecture holds for $m\neq 0$.

Comment: OK, sorry for the inconvenience, but I’m hoping its false.